# Expo dev client: expo run:ios QR code doesn't scan

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to run my expo project on an iOS devise (iOS 15.6 iPhone 12). However, the iPhone doesn't recognize the QR code produced with `expo run:ios`, showing message `No usable data found`.

I'm using a `expo-dev-client` because the project has dependencies that have custom native code, and I have Expo Go installed on my iPhone. I'm utilizing Managed Workflow.

When I run the project on an iOS simulator, the app works. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Output from `npx expo-env-info`:

```
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 12.2.1
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 14.17.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.18 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/yarn
      npm: 8.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~45.0.0 => 45.0.6 
      react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
      react-dom: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
      react-native: 0.68.2 => 0.68.2 
      react-native-web: 0.17.7 => 0.17.7 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 0.56.0
      expo-cli: 6.0.2
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

[image: expo qr code]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? I have the exact same problem but can't find any way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dev client on your phone before scanning the QR code.
[Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/build/internal-distribution/)